# How can we get sockets list from select() function?

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, select, io

I'm working on a network project and I know select() function (with FD_XXX) returns the total number of socket handles that are ready and contained in the fd_set structures but do we know these sockets (as SOCKET or INT)? There is only way to get sockets list with a FOR LOOP-CHECK FD_ISSET, Am I right? else how?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't know why select even returns any other value higher then 1, because it doesn't help anyway.

Comment: Most systems have alternative ways to wait for I/O events, that are better suited if you have a large number of files descriptors. For example Linux has the syscalls [epoll(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll) and `epoll_wait(2)` returns the list of ready file descriptors.

Comment: @nosid What's pool()'s synonym in windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what others say about the return value of select(), I use it this way when dealing with a lot of sockets, it does not guarantee that you don't have to process all the list in case the only one socket happens to be the last one but would save some code if it's the first one.

```
int i;
int biggest=0;
fd_set sfds;
struct timeval timeout={0, 0};

FD_ZERO(&sfds);
for (i=0; i < NumberOfsockets; i++)
{
    FD_SET(SocktList[i], &sfds);
    if (SocktList[i] > biggest) biggest=SocktList[i];
}

timeout.tv_sec=30;
timeout.tv_usec=0;

// biggest is only necessary when dealing with Berkeley sockets,
// Visual Studio C++ (and others) ignore this parameter.
if ((nReady=select((biggest+1), &sfds, NULL, NULL, TimeOut)) > 0)
{
   for (i=0; i < NumerbsOfSocket && nReady > 0; i++)
   {
      if (FD_ISSET(SocketList[i], &sfds)) {
         // SocketList[i] got data to be read
         ... your code to process the socket when it's readable...
         nReady--;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: perfect example! Thanks for this! What dou you think about high-performance sockets? Is select() method suitable for it? What else?

Comment: Well, can you define "high performance" in terms of what would you measure the performance?  Speed?,  Portability?, Ease to maintain? If you have a Gigabyte network card and a four processors machine I think you won't face any problems reading data from the network using select and going thru' the list to pick up the corresponding socket. If you have a lot of opened sockets the bottleneck could be in the network card itself. Also you may consider using various threads to process the sockets, each thread would have its own list of sockets.

Comment: Oh, high-performance that means speed + handling sockets I/O for me. Also I'm asking this for software, not for hardware. (namely that is not a good idea)